# Email-To-Case Is not Triggering an Email to Queue Members

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder, queue

We set up email-to-case. When somebody emails our support address, we want the queue that gets assigned to receive a notification. This notification should also be sent to all of the queue's members.

Inside of Salesforce, we set - Send Email to Members to true.

Does Email-To-Case not trigger these types of emails to the queue members?

we also set up the following logic to run when a case is created via email. It triggers from the process builder:

```
public class AssignCasesUsingAssignmentRules {

public class Request 
{
    @InvocableVariable(label='Case Id For Input' description='yourDescription' required=true)
    public String individualCaseId;
}


@InvocableMethod(label='Rerun Case Assignment Rules' description='Runs the Case Assignment Rules' )
public static void CaseAssign(List<Request> requests)
{
    Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
    dmo.AssignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = true;
    dmo.EmailHeader.TriggerUserEmail = true;
    dmo.EmailHeader.TriggerOtherEmail = true;
    dmo.EmailHeader.triggerAutoResponseEmail = true;

    List<SObject> listOfCasesToUpdate = new List<SObject>();

    for(Request individualRequest: requests )
    {
        Case individualCase = new Case();

        individualCase.Id = individualRequest.individualCaseId;
        individualCase.setOptions(dmo);

        listOfCasesToUpdate.add(individualCase);
    }


    database.update(listOfCasesToUpdate, dmo);
```

}
}

Nothing seems to be able to trigger all members of the queue to receive a case assignment notification.

Comment: in your assignment rule that sets the owner to be a queue, is there an email template identified?

Comment: @cropredy Yes, we ran through a ton of forums before posting this question.